# Does Devarim 30:4 hint at space travel possibility?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, outer-space, parashat-nitzavim

Devarim 30:4 says "Even if your exiles are at the end of the heavens, the Lord, your God, will gather you from there, and He will take you from there."

Why does it use the expression "בִּקְצֵ֣ה הַשָּׁמָ֑יִם " - at the end of heavens? We would expect it to say "at the end[s] of the Earth". I suppose it can be read metaphorically, signifying any place no matter how far.

But if we read it literally,  "end of heavens" seems to signify outer reaches of space. If this verse is speaking about the time Moshiach, then can it be hinting that Jews will live on other planets/solar systems/galaxies?

Comment: Perhaps if you consider hashamayim shamayim ladoshem … then space travel is not contemplated for mankind

Comment: Considering the rather "primitive" knowledge of astronomy at the time this was written, and assuming that since it is Devarim, that most likely Moshe wrote this of his own thinking, and that prior to (I think) Galilelo, the overall thinking was a geocentric world, why can't the term בִּקְצֵ֣ה הַשָּׁמָ֑יִם mean "the horizon"?

Comment: But to argue differently : 1) Torah is eternal, so it was given for all generations, including ours and future ones with advanced knowledge of astrology 2) Moshe said those words through Divine inspiration - and thus we can derive Biblical level commandments from the text of Devarim

Comment: Ibn Ezra reads "the end of the heavens" to mean "antipodal to Eretz Yisrael".

Comment: "Israel, My firstborn"  Does that hint at other sons?  It's the language of men and most men at the time probably pointed at the sky a lot..